# mysql how to determine what to do on delete? Cascade, restrict?

Tags: mysql, innodb, foreign-key-relationship

I know how to detect the foreign tables, foreign fields, references. But I dont know what to do, `CASCADE` or `SET TO NULL`. Describe table wont return this information, neither `information_schema`. Then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` command to see everything (all fields, their types, foreign keys, etc.)

If you are using the data programmatically, then you can query it from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` table using the `UPDATE_RULE` and `DELETE_RULE` columns

Comment: yes, but its very hard to extract that info from it (in PhP code)

Comment: @John - ahh, ok, updated my answer with the table/columns you need from information schema.